# Sending .send requests in loop only sets the last value of the loop i amount of times

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

```
let batch = new this.web3.BatchRequest();

const arr = [
    {name: "test1", att: 100, def: 100},
    {name: "test2", att: 100, def: 100},
    {name: "test3", att: 100, def: 100},
    {name: "test4", att: 100, def: 100},
]
arr.forEach((d) => {
    batch.add(this.contract.methods.createCountry(d.name, d.att, d.def, 10, this.account).send.request(this.contractObject, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    }));
});
console.log(batch);
batch.execute();
```

All values in the contract are set to "test4"

I know it's not the smart contract that is the problem since I tested it thoroughly in Remix and with separate country pushes. I use web3 and Metamask.

Comment: Is this actually the code you're running? The title of your post mentions `i`, which kind of makes it sound like you're using a `for` loop, where the loop variables scope can cause challenges like what you describe.

Comment: I totally get your point, sorry fir the confusion. I used to be running a for loop, not anymore and i actually found a solution for the issue that ill now post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When sending many transactions back-to-back, you have to set the *nonce* for each transaction, and also increment it. Normally the nonce is set for you by the node, but it doesn't work for multiple sequential transactions.

The reason why only the *last* transaction is actually sent, is because the *nonce* can be used as a way to **override** transactions before they are mined (like if you sent it with too little gas).

I have answered this question earlier, with code example

[Repeating transactions hangs - web3js, local geth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495879/repeating-transactions-hangs-web3js-local-geth/49537598#49537598)

Comment: Even though this looks like a logical way to solve my issue, I could not get your solution to work in my context.